# How can I copy Excel cell's value & text format via "=" operator?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Given a sample plain Excel file [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6194904/2013/copy%20excel%20cell%20value%20and%20formation.xlsx), how can we have the target cell to have both the value & text format of the source cell rather than the plain text value only?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test but I think Tom's answer [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/36462-copy-cell-formatting-thru-formula.html) may help you. AFAIK, no function can copy the formatting.

UPDATE:
Note that I am using Microsoft Excel on Mac OSX. Hope that below step works fine with MS Excel on Windows.

- Press Alt + F11 to open Visual basic editor (or Tool > Macro > Visual basic Editor).
- Right click on a sheet in the project windows, choose "View code"
- Paste below codes and press 'Run'

> ```
>  Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
>  Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A8").Copy Range("A8")
>  End Sub
> ```

If you use password to protect you workbook, use below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
ActiveSheet.Unprotect ("YourPassword")
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A8").Copy Range("A8")
ActiveSheet.Protect ("YourPassword")
End Sub
```

That's it. Now the cell "A8" of current sheet will got Sheet1!A8's values and formatting.

Comment: So that is a macro. Can we have a similar user-defined function?

Comment: Let's create a macro with parameters then use it like build-in functions wherever you want.